# Finding a linear transformation generated kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Find a linear transformation $T: \Bbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ such that $\ker(T) = [(1,1,0)]$

My attempt was:

As $\dim(\ker(T)) = 1$, it is necessary to complete with 2 vectors, since dim ($\Bbb{R}^3) = 3$ . So $\beta = {(1,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,1)}$. With $T(1,0,0) = (1,0)$ and $T(0,0,1) = (0,1)$. And the basis $\beta$ is LI, because $\det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = -1$ .

$(x,y,z) = a(1,1,0)+b(1,0,0)+c(0,0,1)$. We have $a = y$ , $b = x-y$ and $c = z$.

Thereby, $(x,y,z) = y(1,1,0)+(x-y)(1,0,0)+z(0,0,1)$.

Thus, $T(x,y,z) = yT(1,1.0)+(x-y)T(1,0,0)+zT(0,0,1)$.

$T(x,y,z) = y(0,0)+(x-y)(1,0)+z(0,1)$.

$T(x,y,z) = (x-y,z)$.

I know it's not unique, but I'm not sure my sequence is correct.

Comment: Your transformation clearly maps $(1,1,0)$ to $(0,0)$ and is linear. That's all you need.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Is my solution incorrect or is there a simpler way?

Comment: The definition of the kernel is $T(v)=0$ with $T$ linear. This allows you to double check your work. Is $T$ linear? Is $T((1,0,0))=(0,0)$? As for a simpler method, it's hard to argue that linear equations are simple as we can always solve them. I can't say that about a lot of equations.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thanks for the clarification